# Как оптимизировать скорость загрузки сайта на WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, оптимизация

Есть сайт http://texnofinance.com/, тема покупная, очень долго грузит, сайт простой, но плагинов Js там около 40 включенных, не знаю зачем.
Изображения оптимизировал, кэш включил, что еще можно сделать, чтобы кардинально увеличить скорость загрузки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Отключить ненужные шрифты (Шрифты для текста занимают много Kb).
2. Отключить ненужные скрипты.
3. Отключить ненужные стили.
4. Сжать фото (например: я взял фото `slide_3.jpg` (109Kb) и уменьшил до 30Kb без уменьшения качества фото).
5. Сжать код Js ([jscompress.com](http://jscompress.com/))  и Css ([csscompressor.com](http://csscompressor.com/)) через онлайн компрессор.

Comment: @Александр Лазневой Если этот ответ вам помог поставьте галочку напротив ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Тема действительно отжирает кучу всего. За время готовности главной страницы было произведено 170 HTTP запросов, среди которых подгрузка скриптов тоже происходит часто. Это не гуд. Кто-то использует различные инструменты, чтобы сливать JS файлы по чанкам (чанк с вендорами, т.е., контрибными библиотеками типа jQuery, Backbone, underscore и т.д., чанк с коммон-функциями и чанк с точкой входа темы/приложения). Более рукастые используют webpack, это очень мощный инструмент юайщика.

Увы, но чаще всего на пыхе проблемы в кривом коде. Особенно, если это плагины, которые друг с другом могут просто конфликтовать и убивать приложение. Попробуй установить профайлер (например xhprof, [здесь описано, как подружить его с вордпрессом](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-xhprof-profiler/installation/)). Когда поставишь и настроишь его - погуляй по сайту. Профайлер сгенерирует логи, в которых явно будет видно кто отжирает огромную кучу ресурсов. Если никто не спалится - проблема на фронтенде. Если минификация и обобщение JS не помогут, я бы смотрел в сторону сервера. Возможно что-то есть там. В крайнем случае, можно поставить memcached ([тык](https://wpmag.ru/2014/memcached-wordpress/)). Это очень мощный инструмент для кеширования. По сути, им можно решить много проблем.

Но, что я вижу: главная страница генерируется достаточно долго, другие страницы генерируются быстрее. Это не гуд. Идет много запросов на статику. Это не гуд. Лично я бы попробовал в первую очередь поставить профайлер.

Answer (score -1):

используйте плагин для кеширования

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?